# is there a way to overwrite catch function in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch

here is the code

```js
function xyz() {
  try {
    var a = someexecutions();
    handlesuccess(a)
  } catch (err) {
    handleerror(err)
  }
}
```

this kind of function written any many times in my codebase I want

```js
function xyz() {
  try {
    var a = someexecutions();
    handlesuccess(a)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`function xyz throw ${err} from file ${__fileName}`)
    handleerror(err)
  }
}
```

but writing this anywhere is very huge work since there are more than 100 functions so I think if I am able to overwrite the catch function then it will work for me somehow. So is there any way for doing this

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. It's part of the language. What you can do:

- Use your IDE to search & replace
- Put your code inside `handleerror` function

Hundred instances are not that much, you can do it :)

Comment: actually, handleerror is not same in all the casese

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If handleerror is a globally shared function you may be able to extract the error's context function name through the non-standard `stack` error property or `arguments.callee`.

Otherwise you could possibly use a regex-based find and replace or a parser to rewrite the code programmatically.